# check and print nodes in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

Partial XML

```
<Notes>
<Note>Line 1</Note>
<Note>Line 2</Note>
<Note>Line 2</Note>
</Notes>
```

Partial XSLT

```
<xsl:for-each select="/Notes/Note">
<xsl:value-of select=".">
</xsl:value-of>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Output:

```
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
```

I want to be able to print only the first two lines. Or a message stating "No Notes". But, I don't understand how to count exactly two or check for a lack of any elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `position()` and only print `note` elements with a position() <=2 :

```
 <xsl:for-each select="/Notes/Note[position() &lt;= 2]">
   <xsl:value-of select=".">
   </xsl:value-of>
 </xsl:for-each>
```

Result:

```
Line 1
Line 2
```

Note that `<` has to be escaped as `&lt;` in the select statement.

And you can check if there are any `note` elements inside `notes`  using `xsl:choose`, printing `No Notes` in case there are none and processing the `xsl:for-each` looop in case there are:

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="/Notes/Note">
        <xsl:for-each select="/Notes/Note[position() &lt;= 2]">
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>No Notes</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

For reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/position

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:template match="Notes[not(*)]">
  <xsl:text>No Notes</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<!-- ignore everything after the second note -->
<xsl:template match="Note[2]/following-sibling::Note"/>
```

The first two notes will be printed by default template rules it depends how you want them formatted.

Similarly Notes with child Notes will be processed by the built in rules.